# Not able to get the image captured from custom camera in another activity

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception, android-sdcard

I have a custom camera in my application with which I capture a picture, and save it in SD card within a folder. I am able to capture the image,but I need to get the image in another activity. I get Failure delivering result and NullPointer Exception in the onActivityResult event. I know that the image is being saved as I can see the path of the image, but the image itself is displayed in the folder after some random period of time. I am not sure if this can be the reason for NullPointerException. I have been trying various solutions from StackOverflow but not has solved the problem. Please somebody help me asap.

Here are snippets of my code:
CustomCameraActivity.java file:

```
public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";
CameraPreview camPreview;
Button btn_take_pic, btn_use_pic;
Camera mCamera;
String fileName;
Activity act;
Context ctx;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    act = this;
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_camera);

    camPreview = new CameraPreview(this,
            (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
    camPreview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(camPreview);
    camPreview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    addListenerForButton();

}
private void addListenerForButton() {

    btn_take_pic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_take_pic);
    btn_take_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Before taking picture");
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
            Log.e(TAG, "After taking picture");
            btn_take_pic.setText("Retake");
            // mCamera.startPreview();

        }
    });
btn_use_pic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_usePhoto);
    btn_use_pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = getOutputMediaFile();
            Log.e("use_pic buttn ", file.getPath());
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("output", file.getPath());
            finish();

        }
    });
}
...
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Reached jpegcallback");
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.e("blah3", "picture file was null!");
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "picture file not found!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "hooray " + pictureFile.toURI().getRawPath());
    }

};
private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    Log.e(TAG, "Get me the o/p file");
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "PostcareApp");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("PostcareApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    Log.e(TAG, "Before returning " + mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Activity where the image is needed:

```
public class HowItWorksActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btn_Account, btn_Photo, btn_Edit, btn_Flip, btn_Post;
RelativeLayout rl;
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2500;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
Bitmap postcard_image;
Uri uri_image;
...
private void takepicture() {
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(HowItWorksActivity.this,CustomCameraActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.e("Howitworks..", "in activityresult");
    String imgfile = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("output");
    Log.e("image ", imgfile);
if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
postcard_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgfile);
        postcard_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(postcard_image,
                metrics.widthPixels, 600, true);
        imgview.setImageBitmap(postcard_image);
 }
}
```

Here is LogCat file:

```
12-06 12:27:40.779: E/CameraActivity(16607): Get me the o/p file
12-06 12:27:40.779: E/CameraActivity(16607): Before returning /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/PostcareApp/IMG_20131206_122740.jpg
12-06 12:27:40.779: E/use_pic buttn(16607): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/PostcareApp/IMG_20131206_122740.jpg
12-06 12:27:41.309: E/Howitworks..(16607): in activityresult
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2500, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.sample.postcare2/com.sample.postcare2.HowItWorksActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3387)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3437)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1291)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at com.sample.postcare2.HowItWorksActivity.onActivityResult(HowItWorksActivity.java:217)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4740)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3383)
12-06 12:27:41.499: E/AndroidRuntime(16607):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use static for Uri,like this 
`private static Uri uri_image.`
Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I know I have declared Uri uri_image but I am not using it currently. I have taken the file path as a string (see above) and I cannot get the string too in these 2 lines :String imgfile = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("output");
  Log.e("image ", imgfile); I just get the exception.

Comment: you need to use intent.setData()..instead of intent.putExtras() ,then only your onActivity result will understand . like this      intent.setData(uri);
uri = data.getData();

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "this is the uri for the iamge path:\n" +
                     data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you see the logcat file above data=null, so I am not sure of your answer. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue. Actually we require following java files.
 1. OnPictureSavedListener ( interface )
 2. CustomCameraActivity which extends Activity implements OnPictureSavedListener 
 3. Preview which extends SurfaceView
 4. PhotoHandler which implements  android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback
 5. PhotoHelper it contains method to create dir and method to get optimal preview size etc
and a xml file named activity_custom_camera.xml.
following permisions are required

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

1. this is interface OnPictureSavedListener

   package ali.customcamera;

   ```
   public interface OnPictureSavedListener {

       public void onPictureSaved(String imagePath);
   }
   ```

2: this is CustomCameraActivity class

```
 package ali.customcamera;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements
            OnPictureSavedListener, Preview.Callback {
        private Preview mPreview;
        Button btnCapture;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_camera);
            mPreview = (Preview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
            btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
            btnCapture.setOnClickListener(captureClick);
        }

        OnClickListener captureClick = new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    //          Progresss.start(CustomCameraActivity.this);
                PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(
                        CustomCameraActivity.this, CustomCameraActivity.this, 0);
                mPreview.takeScreenshot(photoHandler);
                btnCapture.setClickable(false);
            }
        };

// this is where we get the path of the image saved in sdcard
        @Override
        public void onPictureSaved(String imagePath) {
            // Progresss.stop();
            btnCapture.setClickable(true);
            if (imagePath != null && !imagePath.equals("")){
                Intent i = getIntent();
                i.putExtra("imagePath",imagePath );
                setResult(2500, i);
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cameraReady() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void cameraNotAvailable() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

3: this is Preview class

```
package ali.customcamera;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;




public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Callback mCallback;
    Activity mActivity;
    static boolean hasCamera = false;
    Context context;
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes;
    Camera.Size previewSize;
    private PhotoHandler photoHandler;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean configured;


    public   Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        initHolder();
    }

    public   Preview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
        initHolder();
    }
    public   Preview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initHolder();
    }
    public void setCallback(Callback c) {
        mCallback = c;
        mActivity = (Activity) c;
    }


    public interface Callback {
        public void cameraReady();
        public void cameraNotAvailable();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void initHolder() {
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void takeScreenshot(PhotoHandler mPhotoHandler ) {

        try {

            this.photoHandler = mPhotoHandler;
            photoHandler.setCamDimensions(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            photoHandler.setSurfaceDimensions(width, height);
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, mPhotoHandler);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.getCause();
        }

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        mHolder = holder;
        initCamera();

    }

    public void initCamera() {
        if (!hasCamera) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                hasCamera = true;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                hasCamera = false;
                mCallback.cameraNotAvailable();
                return;
            }
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                hasCamera = false;
            }
        }
    }



    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

        width = w;
        height = h;

        if(!configured){
            configureCamera();
        }

        try 
        {
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    private void configureCamera(){

        Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        Display display = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
        {
            previewSize = PhotoHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(previewSizes, width, height, true);

            //parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width);//AQAG
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

        else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90)
        {
            previewSize = PhotoHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(previewSizes, width, height, false);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);   
            //parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width); 

        }

        else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_180)
        {
            previewSize = PhotoHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(previewSizes, width, height, true);
            //parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.height, previewSize.width);   AQAG
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);   
        }

        else if(display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_270)
        {
            previewSize = PhotoHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(previewSizes, width, height, false);

            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    }



    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        releaseCamera();
    }

    public void releaseCamera() {
        if (hasCamera) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            hasCamera = false;
        }
    }
}
```

4:this is PhotoHandler class

```
package ali.customcamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.util.Log;



public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

    private final Context context;

    private OnPictureSavedListener picTakenListener;
    private int camWidth;
    private int camHeight;
    private int surfaceWidth;
    private int surfaceHeight;
    private int offset = 0;



    public PhotoHandler(Context context, OnPictureSavedListener listener, int offset/*, boolean isPortrait*/ ) {
        this.context = context;
//      this.topImage = topOverlayImg;
        this.picTakenListener = listener;
//      this.isPortrait = isPortrait;
        this.offset = offset;

    }

    public void setCamDimensions(int width, int height){

        camWidth = width;
        camHeight = height;

        /*dWidth= width;
        dHeight = height ;*/
    }

    public void setSurfaceDimensions(int width, int height){

        surfaceWidth = width;
        surfaceHeight = height;


    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = PhotoHelper.getOutputMediaFile(PhotoHelper.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        if (pictureFile == null){
            return;
        }

        try {

            //Save camera image to file
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            int len1 = data.length;
            fos.write(data,0, len1);
            fos.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Camera", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Camera", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        camera.startPreview();

        if(picTakenListener!=null){
            picTakenListener.onPictureSaved(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }







}
```

5: this is PhotoHelper class

```
package ali.customcamera;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhotoHelper {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
//  private static final  String dirName = "CustomCamera";
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM/*DIRECTORY_PICTURES*/), "CustomCamera");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateBitmap90(Bitmap bitMap ){
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(90);

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMap, 0, 0, 
                bitMap.getWidth(), bitMap.getHeight(), 
                mat, true);
    }


    public static Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h, boolean isPortrait) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;

        double targetRatio;

        if(isPortrait){
            targetRatio=(double)h / w;
        }
        else{
            targetRatio=(double)w / h;
        }

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

finally, this is layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ali.customcamera.Preview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Capture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have changed the above code as:
    public void onClick(View v) { 
      Log.e("use_pic buttn ",pictureFile.getPath());
      Uri uri_img = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setData(uri_img);finish();
   } 
Here pictureFile is static File variable and it is assigned a value in  PictureCallback().
Then I have used uri_image = getIntent().getData(); in OnActivityResult(), but it still gives me the same error as shown above in Logcat file.

Comment: check this link. May be helpful to you.  https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/src/com/commonsware/android/picture/PictureDemo.java